# Filter problem? Can't get and calculate with dates

Tags: date, swiftui, filter, swift-data

I have two models, one for Bonsai and one for Tasks:

```swift
@Model
final class BonsaiModel {
    var uuid: UUID
    var timestamp: Date
    var purchased: Date
    var price: Int
    var name: String
    var isFavorite: Bool
    var age: Int

    @Attribute(.externalStorage)
    var bonsaiImageData: Data?

    @Relationship(deleteRule: .nullify, inverse: \CategoryModel.bonsai)
    var category: CategoryModel?
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .nullify, inverse: \SpeciesModel.bonsai)
    var species: SpeciesModel?

    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \TaskModel.bonsai)
    var newTaskModel: [TaskModel] = []

    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \BonsaiImageModel.bonsai)
    var bonsaiImages: [BonsaiImageModel] = []

    init(name: String = "",
         isFavorite: Bool = false,
         bonsaiImageData: Data? = nil
    ) {
        self.uuid = UUID()
        self.timestamp = Date()
        self.purchased = Date()
        self.price = Int()
        self.name = name
        self.isFavorite = isFavorite
        self.age = 2023
        self.bonsaiImageData = bonsaiImageData

    }

}

@Model
final class TaskModel {
    var uuid: UUID
    var name: String
    var timestamp: Date
    var isComplete: Bool
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .nullify, inverse: \CareTypeModel.newTask)
    var careType: CareTypeModel?
    var isDue: Date

    var bonsai: BonsaiModel?

    init(
        name: String = "",
        isComplete: Bool = false
    ){
        self.uuid = UUID()
        self.name = name
        self.timestamp = Date()
        self.isComplete = isComplete
        self.isDue = Date()
    }
}
```

One Bonsai can have multiple tasks. Everything works fine.

Now, I want to show the days, until the next Task for a given Bonsai is due.

In my View (refactored) I get my data like so:

```swift
@Environment(\.locale) private var locale
    @State var bonsai = BonsaiModel() // To get me one Bonsai.
    @Query private var taskModel: [TaskModel] // To get all Tasks.
```

My thought was, to get all tasks, then filter tasks to get given Bonsai.
Next get the isDue date and in the end, task-date minus actual date equals days left until task.

I have played with filter, but I don't get it to work. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I figured the correct filter.

My Solution:

```
 let getTask = taskModel.filter({ $0.bonsai == bonsai })
                            let actualTasks = getTask.last
                            let taskDue = taskDate?.isDue
```